# Read data from cloudant db and then compare the value based on specific attribute

Tags: node-red, cloudant

I am working on flow in node red .The flow works to read data from cloudant database and then make if condition to check payload for two document based on the attributes. if  these attributes are equal for a specific value or not. The problem, I received array with objects, show if the condition does not work with me.the flow and the output shown in the following link

[image]

[image]

the code for funcation node :

```js
context.data = context.data || 0.0;
context.data1 = context.data1 || 0.0;

if (msg.topic === 'image') {
  context.data1 = msg.payload;
} else if (msg.topic === 'Sniffer') {
  context.data = msg.payload;
}

if (msg.payload === "aldo" && msg.payload.MAC >0 ) {
  node.status({fill:"red",shape:"ring",text:"disconnected"});
} else {
  node.status({fill:"red",shape:"ring",text:"disconnected"});
}
return msg;

//return context.data1;
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear what goal is here, The second if statement does the same thing for both states. Also if you want to work with the array in `msg.payload` you will probably need a loop to iterate over the entries.

Comment: @ hardillb, Thanks, Sir,  for your reply, The goal is to read all documents in the cloudant db then checking process will happen after that.For example, after reading if statement will check  if a value for name ="aldo"   which is in document 1  && the location =" UK" which in document 2 then send true else false.